# (C#) Getting "Access Denied" error when creating remote powershell session

Tags: c#, powershell, iis, permissions, exchange-server

I have a problem with C# and powershell. I have a ASP.net WebApi running on a server, and I need it to open a remote powershell session with Microsoft Exchange to get some data from room mailboxes. I use this code to connect:

```
PowerShell instance = PowershellHelper.Instance;

instance.AddScript("$passUnsafe = \"" + Password + "\";" +
"$pass = $passUnsafe | convertto-securestring -AsPlainText -Force;" +
"$UserCredential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist \"" + Username + "\",$pass;" +
"if (!(Get-PSSession | Where { $_.ConfigurationName -eq \"Microsoft.Exchange\" })) { $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection; }" +
"else { $Session = (Get-PSSession | Where { $_.ConfigurationName -eq \"Microsoft.Exchange\" })[0]; }" +
"Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking;");

PowershellHelper.Instance.Streams.Error.Clear();
instance.Invoke();
```

This works fine on my local machine, but not in a remote server. The script crashes trying to do "New-PSSession" with the following error:

```
[outlook.office365.com] Connecting to remote server outlook.office365.com failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

After some research, I found this happens because non-admin users are not allowed to execute remote session commands. If I add the IIS application pool user to the Administrators group, it works fine, but I want to avoid that if possible.
Some people say you can add the user to the Built-in "Remote Management Users" group, but it didn't work for me. I even tried to change the user permissions directly, giving it full access, but it doesn't work either. It only works if I add it to the Administrators group. It seems there's something else blocking the execution, or the IIS is ignoring the user groups. The credentials are fine. Do anyone knows if there's any other way to execute remote powershell commands without admin permissions?

Comment: Sounds like a limitation with the `Microsoft.Exchange` configuration.

Comment: PowerShell remoting has its own settings. Did you check the REST API? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations ? I think that's more suitable with granular permission checks.

Comment: Outlook REST API uses a robust authentication system that requires registering my app, and also user interaction to input the credentials. I want to avoid that, as I have the username and password in plain text (the app I'm making doesn't require any kind of security measure). I want to do everything with Powershell and SMTP. The only useful API I found was Exchange Web Services Managed API, but it's going to be deprecated in a couple of years, so I can't use it.

Comment: I'm not sure if you try to Run script as Administrator and Enable remote processing mode.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue last week while migrating a web-based user provisioning application from its Exchange 2010 target to Exchange 2016. Ultimately, the problem was a permission issue on the application server. The `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool` identity was trying to write a value to `HKU:\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\CurrentVersion\WSMAN\Client\ConnectionCookies`.

I granted the `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool` identity Full Control permission on the ConnectionCookies key, and the application was able to successfully invoke `New-PSSession`.

I discovered this resolution on a blog called Mike's Ramblings here (Blogspot): http://codermike.blogspot.com/2016/06/new-pssession-access-denied.html

Mike discovered the issue with Process Monitor. I was able to do the same by running Process Monitor, reproducing the issue, and searching for any events with an ACCESS DENIED result. Double-clicking on an event and clicking the Process tab will reveal the invoking user.

I still don't understand why the `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool` identity is trying to create this value when my application uses a dedicated app pool with a service account identity.

In the words of Mark Russinovich: "When in doubt, Process Monitor."

Answer (score 0):

Per Simon Li's comments you can give your account remote PowerShell execution permissions with the following PowerShell script:

```
Set-User "XXXXX" -RemotePowerShellEnabled $true
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-server/control-remote-powershell-access-to-exchange-servers?view=exchange-ps

Comment: Made no difference for me. I didn't expect it to either because adding the Application Pool Identity to the local Administrators resolves group resolves the issue. This implies it is a problem on the web server and not the Exchange server. Also it's not clear to me what "your account" refers to here. Is it the Application Pool Identity or the user you use to authenticate against the remote Exchange server or something else?